# Convert tabulated column to array

Tags: arrays, split, tabs

My input is copied from a HTML table and looks like this in text format:

1 2 3

4 5 6

(imagine 'tabs' instead of the spaces)

The String would become then:

1\t\2\t3\r\n4\t5\t6

How can I create an array so that:

myArray(0,0) returns 1
 myArray(0,1) returns 2
 myArray(1,0) returns 4

I have tried this:

```
String input = Clipboard.GetText();
String[] content = input.Split(("\t").ToCharArray());
```

but this creates an array with the following elements:
1
2
3\r\n
4
5
6

-- Thank you... --

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how to split it at the tabs, you can split it at the line break too.

```
stringIs = 1\t\2\t3\r\n4\t5\t6

firstSplit = stringIs.split("\r\n");
```

Now you have an array with two elements.

```
firstSplit[0] = "1\t\2\t3";
firstSplit[1] = "4\t5\t6";
```

So just split those the same way into a new array.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is still that (I think) I need a multidimensional array, no? I am at this point where I have an array with the rows, so i have to merge them now?

Comment: Your answer is much appriciated